# Is this an Amiga? If so, which model?

Tags: commodore, identify-this-computer

In the 1998 Swedish comedy musical "Åke från Åstol", there's a moment toward the end when a man is pushing around some sort of Amiga-looking computer with a monitor and mouse on a wheelbarrow. The context of the scene is that this fisherman has just come back from the "big city" after learning about computers and now he is bringing one of them home in order to "sell herring in cyberspace".

Presumably for comedic effect (and probably also prop cost reasons), they seem to have deliberately used an outdated computer, or at least one that would be *perceived* as such by the general public at the time. The relatively cheap Amiga computers were probably a common sight here in the late 1980s or at least early-to-mid 1990s, but not so much by year 1998, when powerful "home PCs" started becoming a thing in many homes, being paid off monthly through the salary with a government deal.

I'm trying to identify what kind of machine this is. It looks like an Amiga of some kind, but I can't read "Amiga" anywhere on the front. Maybe the brand was removed.

[image]

Comment: that actually looks like a Commodore C64C; but the mouse is something else (the only mouse for the 64-era stuff was the 1351, which had two buttons...)

Answer (score 46):

> I'm trying to identify what kind of machine this is. It looks like an Amiga of some kind,

It's a [Commodore C64-II](https://www.c64-wiki.com/wiki/C64C) also known as C64C:

[image: C64-II]

The mouse seems to be an Apple [ADB mouse](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Apple_desktop_mouse.jpg) (Type A9M0331), sold from 1986 until the mid 1990s:

[image]

> but I can't read "Amiga" anywhere on the front. Maybe the brand was removed.

If you look into the lower right, you'll see a tag reading "**commodore 64** PERSONAL COMPUTER":

[image]

Comment: Spot on answer by Raffzahn, it's a Commodore C64C and an Apple Mac ADB mouse, possibly from a Mac SE. They'd never have worked with each other unless heavily modded, but it's nice that they're both of roughly the same era, and sold at the same time (C64C was 1986, MAC SE was 1987). It's hard to believe they were contemporary, when you consider the difference in performance between the two machines, but the price was hugely different.

Comment: Hard to tell if the original is a Swedish layout keyboard or not because the image is too low-res, but your picture definitely isn't.  (Not sure if there was a Swedish version or not.)